# Expand Section in Flutter

Tags: flutter

#### Project

Hi, I'm attempting to recreate this kind of effect in flutter [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVyp3.png) but I'm unable to find a good way of doing it. I want also a simple slide animation between the two states.
My way of doing it was to wrap two AnimatedContainer into a column (the upper container has a fixed height while the bottom one is expanded) but I'm having some problems with overflowing and gestures

#### code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        child: _buildUpperSection(),
        height: _isExpanded ? 0 : 200,
      ),
      AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        child: Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isExpanded = true;
                  });
                }
                if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
                  _isExpanded = false;
                }
              },
              child: _buildBottomSection(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

#### Question

Is there a better way of doing it handling also overflow while container is resizing?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to build a pageview, i only want to resize some expanded widget without causing render overflows

Comment: You can wrap AnimatedContainer with Expended(flex: 1)

Comment: Sorry, i feel like I'm missing your point. Can you provide an example?